# Is the public unaware about the fate of this character in Spider-Man: Far From Home?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

At the beginning of *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, the students from Peter's high school pay their respects

> to the fallen Avengers during their attempt to bring back the snapped people.
>
>
>  In the video **A Memorium to the Lost Avengers** that follows, we see that Captain America is presented alongside the deceased Iron Man, Vision, and Black Widow.

So, is the general public unaware that,

> **Captain America** is still alive (*old, but still ticking*)?

Comment: He *could* be dead now...it's 8 months after *Endgame*....but I suspect he's just "officially" dead.

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you have a source for the 8 months after? I've seen it quoted a few times but last I heard Amy Pascal was quoting it would start "a few minutes after".

Comment: It's stated in the "In memorium" video that the Blip happened 8 months ago.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ah, I should have paid more attention to that part.

Comment: If Sam is taking up his mantel, then the public might not know the difference.

Answer (score 21):

#### Probably but it doesn't matter

I would assume they don't know that he is still alive as that would seem contradictory to him wanting to keep a few things secret (for example, his wife). Per the Avengers side of things, they seem pretty fragmented in *Far From Home* but they too would probably want to keep it a secret out of respect for Steve.

The fact that he is in the video points to the fact that the public almost certainly don't know he is still alive and think he died in the Battle for Earth.

However, it doesn't matter if he died or became too old, he is still no longer an Avenger  and the video is commemorating those Avengers that saved the world that are "no longer with us". For all intents and purposes death and being too old to be of much help are pretty synonymous in the world of being a superhero.

---

It's also worth pointing out that *Far From Home* takes places 8 months after *Endgame* and so Steve *could* have died in that time. I highly doubt he has but he's an old man so it is a possibility.

Answer (score 5):

#### No.

The general public was not aware that the Avengers had traveled to different timelines until Scott Lang, aka Ant-Man, revealed it in his memoir, *[Look Out For The Little Guy!](https://books.google.com/books/about/Look_Out_for_the_Little_Guy.html?id=tIarEAAAQBAJ)* which [came out (in-universe) after the events of *Spider-Man: Far From Home*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/2025#26th_2). Scott tells his story of the Time Heist and the fight against Thanos in his book, but he keeps quiet about Captain America’s current situation. This means that **the public doesn’t know that Captain America is still alive as an elderly man**.

In his book, Scott shares his experience of being part of the [Time Heist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#2020) and other events in *Avengers: Endgame*. He explains in the book’s introductory chapter that he decided to write his memoir after getting encouragement from Bruce Banner (the Hulk) and Clint Barton (Hawkeye), who expressed their concern that **the world didn’t really *know* what had happened** and deserved to know the full story behind Thanos and the Blip, including their travels to alternate timelines. Scott writes:

> One day, Bruce “the Hulk” Banner and Clint “Hawkeye” Barton took me out for lunch. They said they were concerned that the world didn’t really *know* what had happened with Thanos and the Blip and our long struggle to finally put things right again.
>
> At first, as I usually do when confronted with heavy topics, I made a joke: “I’m pretty sure at least half the world knows what happened.”
>
> Bruce responded that yes, of course, billions had *experienced* these jarring and mind-bending events, but they didn’t know the full story behind them. And ultimately, that’s what people need the most to get through and get past traumatic events: a narrative that helps it all make sense.

[Before Scott Lang’s book came out (in-universe)](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/2025#26th_2), Jennifer Walters, the protagonist of *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law*, was unaware of the details behind the Time Heist and assumed that Steve Rogers had died. She mentions this several times in the first episode, “A Normal Amount of Rage”. She refers to Steve using the past tense “was”, reflecting the common belief that he was among the fallen heroes.

However, Bruce Banner, who is Steve’s friend and fellow Avenger, knows that Steve is still alive as an old man. He uses the present tense “is” when talking about Steve with Jennifer, hinting at his secret survival.

Here are dialogue from the first episode, where Jennifer and Bruce discuss Steve Rogers (note the contrast between Jennifer’s and Bruce’s use of “was/is”) (emphasis mine):

> **Jennifer**: Obviously, Captain America **was** a virgin.

Post-credits scene:

> **Jennifer:** [*Drunk crying*] It's just so sad. Steve Rogers did so much for his country and he never got to experience sex.
> [*Crying*]  Did you see that ass? Like, **that ass did not** [*Cries*] **deserve to die** a virgin. It's, like, so sad.
>
> **Bruce:** Steve Rogers **is** not a virgin. He lost his virginity to a girl in 1943 on the USO tour.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we are not sure in which timeline Cap spent his life before passing over the shield to Falcon. The screenwriters of *Avengers: Endgame* says he stayed in the original timeline but in the past, married Peggy, lived here all the time without intervening any evens we saw in the past film. But the directors tell us otherwise (alternate timeline).

Now, no matter which timeline he lives in. The public from original timeline wouldn't know if he's still alive. Either he would be living in another timeline or secretly living a normal life in the original timeline without revealing his identity. So he is actually MIA. That's no matter he is dead or alive why it's obvious for public to assume that he has passed.